# C# foreach set list property to loop index in one line using list.Foreach

Tags: c#, linq

```
int loopIndex = 0;
foreach (var item in dataList)
{
    item.ChannelId = loopIndex;
    loopIndex++;
}
```

I am looking for an alternate of above code in one line. Something like- `dataList.ForEach(x=>x.ChannelId=...)`

Suggestions please.

Comment: Why does it need to be one line? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: dataList is a list of one entity List<Entity> @mjwills

Comment: `dataList.ForEach(item => { item.ChannelId = loopIndex; loopIndex++; });`

Comment: @Sayse Just want to know whether we can set loop index to a list property in list.ForEach instead of using foreach as i used above.

Comment: MoreLINQ's ForEach may also be worth considering - https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ForEach.cs .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you NuGet Microsoft's "System.Interactive" extensions then you can do this:

```
dataList.ForEach((item, index) => item.ChannelId = index);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `Linq` appraoch in one line without the requiremet to install another library

```
dataList = dataList.Select((x, i) => { x.ChannelId = i; return x; }).ToList();
```

Code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SCEbyV

---

another appraoch - the classy `for` loop way in one line

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++) dataList[i].ChannelId = i;
```

Comment: It's a shame that you'd need System.Linq to make this work for any enumerable, better looking that all the others.

Comment: @DanRayson I don't know the type of `dataList` but sure `dataList.Length` or `dataList.Count` would be the better choice if `dataList` is a array or list

Comment: +1 for the for-loop, because it usually has far better performance than the more elegant ForEach with index. Sometimes that's important.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
dataList.ForEach(x => x.ChannelId = loopIndex++);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dataList= dataList.Select(x=>x.ChannelId=loopIndex++).ToList();
```